# Access level fields in Account Team Member objects are not available in formula editor

Tags: process-builder, formula-field

I have created a process based on Account Team Member object. I want to check whether Account Access Level field value has changed. I am using ISCHANGED(AccountAccessLevel) condition in the criteria. When the process executes, I am getting below error.

sfdc.formula.Invalid Field Reference Exception: Field AccountAccessLevel does not exist

Also I have noticed,when I try to create a formula field in Account Team Member object, none of the Access Level fields listed below are available in the formula editor.

AccountAccessLevel
CaseAccessLevel
ContactAccessLevel
OpportunityAccessLevel

Can you please help?

Comment: Please, make sure that you have access to this field from your Profile (even if it is System Administrator). Sometimes, it does not set automatically.

Comment: Also, just want to check your syntax of the formula. Please check below this:- ISCHANGED([AccountTeamMember].AccountAccessLevel)